# AWS EC2 - Secure connection from specific domain to database?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, security, networking, amazon-ec2

I'm using AWS EC2 to run a database that supports search capabilities - similar to Elasticsearch. The database is only running in a single AWS region due to budgetary constraints.

The database is also running inside of a private subnet in a VPC. Currently there are no inbound or outbound connections that it can make.

I need to allow access to the database so that only my serverless functions can connect to it via HTTP. Users should not be allowed to access it directly from the client-side. Using Lambda is possible but is far from ideal due to long cold start times. Users will expect search results to appear very quickly, especially when the page first loads. So something else is required.

The plan is to replace Lambda with Cloudflare Workers. With faster start times and closer distance to end users all over the world, connecting to the database this way would probably give me the speed I need while still offering all the benefits of a serverless approach. However, I'm not sure how I can configure my VPC security group to allow connections only from a specific worker.

I know that my workers all have unique domains such as `https://unique-example.myworkerdomain.com` and they remain the same over time. So is there a way I can securly allow inbound connections from this domain while blocking everything else? Can/should this be done through configuring security groups, internet gateway, IAM role, something else entirely?

Thank you for any help and advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

### ECS

You can run an ECS cluster in the same VPC as your database, and run Fargate tasks, which have sub-second start times (maybe 100ms or less?). And you can run ECS tasks on hot cluster instances (but you then pay for them all the time), but perhaps a scale to/from zero approach with ECS would allow you to manage cost without compromising on most of user requests (the first request after a scale-to-zero event would get 100ms+ latency, but subsequent requests would get similar). Lambda actually does something similar to this under the hood, but with much more aggressive scale-down timelines. This doesn't restrict from a specific domain, but may solve your issue.

### Self-Managed Proxy

Depending on how your database is accessed, you might be able to have a reverse proxy such as Nginx in a public subnet doing request validation to limit access to the database. This could control access by any request headers, but I'd recommend doing TLS client validation to ensure that only your functions can access the database through the proxy, and it might be possible to validate the domain this way (by limiting the trusted CA to an intermediate CA that only signs for that domain, alternatively, I think Nginx can allow a connection depending on traits of the client cert matches regexes such as domain name).

### Route Through Your Corporate Network

Using a VPN, you can originate the function from within your network or somehow filter the request, then the database could still be in a private subnet with connectivity allowed from the corporate network through the VPN.

### Use AWS WAF

You make a public ALB pointing at your database, and set up AWS WAF to block all requests that don't contain a specific header (such as an API key). Note: you may have to also set up Cloudfront, I forget off the top of my head whether you can apply WAF directly to an ELB or not. Also note: I don't particularly advise this, as I don't think WAF was designed with sensitive strings in the rules, so you may have to think about who has describerule / describewebacl permissions on WAF, also these rules may end up in logs because AWS doesn't expect the rules to be sensitive. But it might be possible for WAF to filter on something you find viable. I'm pretty sure you can filter on HTTP headers, but unless those headers are secret, anyone can connect by submitting a request with those headers. I don't think WAF can do client domain validation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! If I were to run a reverse proxy, would there be issues with scalability as more and more users connect? Would this require provisioning large EC2 instances in order to cope with CPU/memory issues?

Comment: If you have a lot of requests, you can put Nginx reverse proxies in an autoscaling group behind a load balancer. If you're connection are not stateless/idempotent, you may have to enable sticky sessions on the load balancer, and do connection-draining on the auto-scaling group to avoid killing long-lived connections. I've done this for stateless web requests and it's worked great. It works less well proxying layer 4 requests that are stateful and long-lived, but can still be viable.

Comment: Come to think of it, you may be able to use an ALB and AWS WAF to filter requests and send them directly to your database(s). I don't know if there's a WAF rule that would satisfy your caller domain constraint. That's a hard thing to do without just trusting the requestor to be who they say they are. But if this is possibly, you wouldn't have to have any extra EC2 infrastructure that you manage, and it would all scale beyond your wildest dreams.

Comment: I see. All of my connections would be stateless HTTP connections so worrying about sticky sessions wouldn't be a problem. AWS WAF can get very expensive rather quickly though so even if there was a rule that worked here it wouldn't be economically viable. But I will do more research on setting up Nginx and see if that is possible. Thanks again

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please accept it as the answer. It helps others when searching for answers. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Yes, I haven't forgotten. I am still looking for an optimal solution, but if it is one that you've suggested then I will accept it as the best answer

Comment: Thank you @TopherIsSwell for your answer. You've pointed me in the right direction and I'm very grateful. Sorry for taking so long to accept it as the answer